# Matplotlib pyplot semilogy broken for specific data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to display data on a semi-log scale using matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy but for some reason certain specific data will not display on a log scale.

Here is the minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y1 = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 50)

x2 = [ 0.5, 0.69230769,  0.88461538,  1.07692308,  1.26923077,  1.46153846,
1.65384615,  1.84615385,  2.03846154,  2.23076923,  2.42307692,  2.61538462,
2.80769231,  3.,          3.19230769,  3.38461538,  3.57692308,  3.76923077,
3.96153846,  4.15384615,  4.34615385,  4.53846154,  4.73076923,  4.92307692,
5.11538462,  5.30769231,  5.5,         5.69230769,  5.88461538,  6.07692308,
6.26923077,  6.46153846,  6.65384615,  6.84615385,  7.03846154,  7.23076923,
7.42307692,  7.61538462,  7.80769231,  8.        ]

y2 = [14.575361987617431, 13.085951334251263, 11.624204239934841, 11.042131295677322, 10.644970825480804,
9.9236653345614503, 9.5062099711101915, 9.3283627736535824, 9.0534046482183932, 8.8134672834907359,
8.4231263934928542, 8.42795792391086, 8.4456426949395116, 8.0627962362862267, 8.164485063139546,
7.9551127994296023, 7.8244362249461439, 7.9030927230355665, 7.7181207757466472, 7.5995483354781648,
7.5188031175401084, 7.5583740928502579, 7.5662853869793665, 7.437330171526578, 7.3623785273467872,
7.3503413700294535, 7.375341864137301, 7.300590983871917, 7.2357339123237017, 7.1353470647499266,
7.1784115809287599, 7.1576686293908374, 7.097654663701598, 6.9911420242692399, 7.0015210243972046,
6.9017431583355604,6.9352210046151539, 6.8707305411431996, 6.7925239329688045, 6.7930737708109978]

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
# plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o-')
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'o-')
plt.title('Linear Scale')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
# plt.semilogy(x1, y1, 'o-')
plt.semilogy(x2, y2, 'o-')
plt.title('Semi-Log Scale')

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, bottom=0.05, hspace = 0.25)

plt.show()
```

Which outputs:
[image: Y-axis not displaying log scale]

But if I plot x1 and y1 instead it seems to work normally:

[image: semilogy working normally]

I'm not sure why this is, maybe there is a bug in semilogy? Does anyone know a workaround?

I'm using matplotlib version 2.1.0 on python version 3.6.3

Comment: Playing around with it I found that if I simply subract the minimum off of y2, it displays on a logarithmic scale. I.e. if I add the line y2 = y2-np.min(y2) before plotting the semilogy the data will plot on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Can you go more in detail about what the exact problem is? It seems all plots above that are labeled "Semi-Log" have indeed a logarithmic y axis. So it would be good to know in how far this is not actually what you are looking for.

Comment: The axes labels are written in log scale format for all plots labled 'Semi-Log Scale', but in the top picture the data is not plotted semi logarithmically. You will notice that in the top picture the top and bottom plot have the exact same same lines and points drawn, despite the y-axis changing from linear to logarithmic. Also the spacing between tick-marks for the top picture is linear in both cases. The bottom picture demonstrates what the semilogy function is supposed to do, and is failing to do for my specific data set (but will do if you offset it, see above comment).

Comment: Simply put, for this data set the semilogy function is plotting the points as if it were a linear scale, despite changing the y-axis to log scale

Comment: Hmmm, after fiddling around with it it seems that the y-axis is indeed logarithmic, it's just that there isn't enough spread in the values to look substantially different from the linear scale. If you set the y-axis limits manually you can see the difference. Not actually a bug just a visual oddity.

Comment: I get the expected y-axis on Linux, using Python 3.5.2 and matplotlib 1.5.2.  After upgrading matplotlib to 2.1.2, I got the linear y-axis you're seeing.  (Update:  Linear-_appearing_ y-axis, it seems.)  I think the 1.5 rendering was much more clear; the 2.1 graph fooled me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misconception. Sometimes you see what you want to see, not what is actually there. The data plot is indeed different and the scale is correct. For sure there is no major difference since the data range is much less than a decade (unlike in the lower plot where it is two decades), but you might observe that in the lower part of the first plot the data is a bit more bumpy and the curvature is different. If not, here is an overlay of both images from which you can see the difference.

[image]